# functional testing with select id in laravel 5.4 (2)

Tags: php, laravel, testing

In my form, I have several select, all the same name, but different Ids.

```
    <form method="POST" action="/"
          accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <select name="directElimination_fighters[]" class="directElimination_select" id="1_1">
            <option selected></option>
            <option value="1639"> Brisa Wisozk </option>
            <option value="1640"> Vicenta Walsh </option>
        </select>
        <select name="directElimination_fighters[]" class="directElimination_select" id="1_2">
            <option selected></option>
            <option value="1639"> Brisa Wisozk </option>
            <option value="1640"> Vicenta Walsh </option>
        </select>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="update">
            Update 
        </button>
    </form>
```

I'm making my functional tests, so I do :

```
    $this->visit('/')
        ->select( '#1_2', 'Brisa Wisozk')
        ->press('update');
```

But PHPUnit says:

InvalidArgumentException: Nothing matched the filter [Brisa Wisozk] CSS query provided for ...

I also tried selecting with ID:

```
$this->visit('/')
        ->select('#1_2', '1639')
        ->press('update');
```

What am I missing???

Comment: The syntax of the last one is correct. Do you get any errors when using it? If not and nothing happens, check also browser console.

Comment: what do you mean browser console? No errors and I can confirm with a dump that value is present

Comment: you're missing double quotes for the classes in select tags and the last one should work as @AlexeyMezenin mentioned

Comment: sorry, I have already corrected the double quotes. not fixing the issue. I will update my code

Comment: try to remove the selected atrr from your first options

Comment: it is quite weird. I replaced options for static ones <option value="111">aaa</option>
    <option value="222">bbb</option> but it still doesn't work...